# How are the roots of a complex polynomial of degree > 4 actually found

Tags: polynomials

I know that there are no general formulas for finding the roots of a complex polynomial of degree greater than 4.  This site contains many questions about the roots of specific polynomials in this category.

The fundamental theorem of algebra says that such roots exist.  How do people go about finding them? Is there something like Newton's method for complex polynomials?

Comment: In fact, Newton's method works also in the complex numbers, but not always. I am not aware of other methods in the complex numbers.

Comment: [Wikipedia: Root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms#Roots_of_polynomials)

Comment: Answer depends on what is the goal. If you need to find exact root value in closed form, it is not always possible. But for specific polynomials it is possible, for example $az^5+b$ roots are easy to find. If you need to find proximate values of roots, then you can use numerical methods.

Comment: Ivan:  Thanks.  How about a link to the numerical methods you favor?